# Limiting port control access

Tags: mxgraph

Is it possible (and can someone demonstrate how) to setup ports with a couple of attributes (e.g. type and direction) to limit the connections that can be made?

As an example, if I'm looking to setup a logic diagram that would have different sections, I might want to limit the output of a gate so that it can only go to the input of a different gate (as opposed to the output of a different gate). I might also want to limit it to the input of a gate in the same section.

Ideally, I would like to be able to highlight the valid targets when the user starts dragging from the port to a destination.

I thought I had seen a demo of this last year when I started looking at graphing/diagramming libraries, but I can't find it now.

Nigel